If $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then solving $Ax = b$ is equivalent to minimizing the quadratic form $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T A x - x^T b$
If $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then solving $Ax = b$ is equivalent to minimizing the quadratic form
$\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T A x - x^T b$.
$\textbf{Proof}$ We will consider changes of $\varphi$ along a certain ray $x + \alpha p$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and fixed direction vector $p \neq 0$.
First we show that $\varphi(x + \alpha p) > \varphi(x)$ if $A$ is symmetric positive definite.
$$
\varphi(x + \alpha p) = \frac{1}{2} (x + \alpha p)^T A (x + \alpha p) - (x + \alpha p)^T b $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} x^T A x + \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 p^T A p + \alpha p^T A x - x^T b - \alpha p^T b $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} x^T A x - x^T b + \alpha p^T A x - \alpha p^T b + \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 p^T A p $$
$$= \varphi(x) + \alpha p^T (Ax - b) + \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 p^T A p.$$
Thus, we see that $\varphi$ (as a quadratic function in $\alpha$ with positive leading coefficient) will have to have a minimum along the ray $x + \alpha p$.
We now decide what the value of $\alpha$ at this minimum is. A necessary condition (and also sufficient since the coefficient of $\alpha^2$ is positive) is
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha} \varphi(x + \alpha p) = 0$$
To this end we compute
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha} \varphi(x + \alpha p) = p^T (Ax - b) + \alpha p^T A p,$$
which has its root at
$$\hat{\alpha} = \frac{p^T (b - Ax)}{p^T A p}.$$
The corresponding minimum value is
$$\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) = \varphi(x) - \frac{[p^T (b - Ax)]^2}{2 p^T A p}.$$
The last equation shows that
$$\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) < \varphi(x) \quad \text{if and only if} \quad p^T (b - Ax) \neq 0,$$

i.e., $\mathbf{p}$ is not orthogonal to the residual $\mathbf{r}
 = \mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{x}.$

To see the equivalence with the solution of the linear system $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ we need to consider two possibilities:
$1. \mathbf{x} $ is such that $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}.$ Then $\varphi(\mathbf{x} + \hat\alpha{\mathbf{p}}) = \varphi(\mathbf{x}) $ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x})$ is the minimum value.
$2.\mathbf{x}$ is such that $A\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{b}.$ Then $\varphi(\mathbf{x} +\hat \alpha{\mathbf{p}}) < \varphi(\mathbf{x})$, i.e., there exists a direction $\mathbf{p}$ such that $\mathbf{p}^T (\mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{v}) \neq 0$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x})$ is not the minimum.
Doubt:- I understood that $\mathbf{p}$ is not orthogonal to the residual $\mathbf{r}
 = \mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{x}.$
I don't understand the two cases
My attempt
We have
$$\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) = \varphi(x) - \frac{[p^T (b - Ax)]^2}{2 p^T A p}.$$
If $b=Ax,$ then $\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) = \varphi(x). $ How does this implies $\varphi(x)$ has minimum value?
Case 2, $\mathbf{x}$ is such that $A\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{b}.$ Then $\varphi(\mathbf{x} + \alpha\hat{\mathbf{p}}) < \varphi(\mathbf{x})$, i.e., there exists a direction $\mathbf{p}$ such that $\mathbf{p}^T (\mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{v}) \neq 0$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x})$ is not the minimum.
I don't understand this. How does these two statement proves the statement of the theorem?

Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882237/equivalence-of-ax-b-and-the-quadratic-form?rq=1

Should some of those $\hat{\mathbf{p}}$'s actually be $\hat{\alpha}$'s?

@user326159 Not a duplicate. I have doubt in the proof.

@WyattKuehster Yes. sorry for the typo


The proof is saying that when $Ax = b$, $\hat{\alpha} = 0$ is the value of the parameter of $\alpha$ that minimizes the expression $\varphi(x+\alpha p)$ and the value of this expression at $\alpha = \hat{\alpha}$ is $\varphi(x)$ by your calculation there.

In the second case, we have that $Ax\neq b$, so $p^T(b-Ax)\neq 0$. But then the quantity $\frac{[p^T(b-Ax)]^2}{2p^TAp}$ is strictly positive (seeing as $A$ is positive definite), so $\varphi(x+\hat{\alpha} p)<\varphi(x)$. Hence $\varphi(x)$ cannot be the minimum value of the expression $\varphi(x+\alpha p)$ because we just found something less than it.


This finishes the proof because what we were trying to prove was that $\varphi(x)$ being the minimum value of $\varphi(x+\alpha p)$ is equivalent to $x$ being the solution to $Ax=b$.
So the logic went $Ax = b$ $\implies $ $\varphi(x)$ is the minimum value of $\varphi(x+\alpha p)$ for every $p$
$Ax\neq b$ $\implies $ $\varphi(x)$ is not the minimum value of $\varphi(x+\alpha p)$ for some $p$

You mean $\mathbf{p}$ is not orthogonal to the residual $\mathbf{r}
= \mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{x}.$ then $\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) < \varphi(x)$. That means $ \varphi($ is maximum at $x$ in all direction $\hat \alpha p$.  If $Ax=b$ is the case. then, $\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) = \varphi(x).$ This means here  $\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) < \varphi(x)$ is false. If there exist $p$ such that $p^T (b - Ax) \neq 0$ we again get $\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) < \varphi(x).$ So, $x$ can't be minimum. Am I correct?

This is correct except the statement that $\varphi(x+\hat{\alpha}p)<\varphi(x)$ implies that $\ varphi$ is maximum at $x$ in all directions $p$. I'm not sure where you got that from.
$p$ is not orthogonal to $r$$\iff$ $p^T(Ax-b) \neq 0\iff \varphi(x+\hat{\alpha}p)<\varphi(x)$ are all equivalent to $\varphi(x)$ not being the minimum.

Since, I consider $x^Ty=\langle x, y \rangle$

Could you tell me how this theory can be used to solve $Ax=b$? How can I develop conjugate gradient method out of it?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4929889/how-do-i-create-conjugate-gradient-method-out-of-this-result  @WyattKuehster
