How do I create conjugate gradient method out of this Result?
How do I create conjugate gradient method out of this Result?
My attempt:-
If $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then solving $Ax = b$ is equivalent to minimizing the quadratic form
$\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T A x - x^T b$.
We will consider changes of $\varphi$ along a certain ray $x + \alpha p$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and fixed direction vector $p \neq 0.$
We got $\varphi(x)$ is minimum when $b=Ax.$ because $$\varphi(x + \hat{\alpha} p) = \varphi(x) - \frac{[p^T (b - Ax)]^2}{2 p^T A p}.$$
In the first iteration, we take $x=x_0.$ Hence $r_0=b-Ax_0$ and choose $p_0=r_0.$
How does this choice diminish the quantity $\hat\alpha_0=\frac{[p^T (b - Ax)]^2}{2 p^T A p}?$
Now new direction will be $x_1=x_0+\hat\alpha_0 p_0$
Update residual : $r_1=r_0-Ax_1.$ Am I correct? I am unable to prove the Algorithm given in the notebook. Why do they do like this? What is the benefit of this method? How does this iteration work? In my notebook only this theorem given and Algorithm for the Conjugate gradient method.Could you please explain the idea behind the algorithm?
Thank you in advance.

Recommended https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf
